# DevExpress VerticalGrid set value of cell that has no fieldname

Tags: devexpress

In the DevExpress VerticalGrid  `InitNewRecord` event, I am able to set the cell value when the row has a value in the `fieldname` property:

```
 string zipcode = "99999";
VGrid.SetCellValue(VGrid.GetRowByFieldName("zipcode"), e.RecordIndex, zipcode);
```

However, for rows with no value in their `fieldname` property, I am unable to do so. This is not working:

```
  string city = "unknown";
  VGrid.SetCellValue(VGrid.Rows["rowcity"], e.RecordIndex, city);
```

The row's `(Name)` property contains the value **rowcity**.   I'm trying to get the row by its name.

I have also tried

```
 string city = "unknown";
  VGrid.SetCellValue(rowcity, e.RecordIndex, city);
```

where I'm trying to get the row using the member that has been automatically created.

I've also tried casting **rowcity** to *BaseRow*:

```
  string city = "unknown";
  DevExpress.XtraVerticalGrid.Rows.BaseRow mybaserow;
  mybaserow = (DevExpress.XtraVerticalGrid.Rows.BaseRow) rowcity;
  VGrid.SetCellValue(mybaserow, e.RecordIndex, city);
```

Have also tried via Properties:

```
  VGrid.SetCellValue(  rowcity.Properties, e.RecordIndex, "unknown");
```

but no joy.

What am I overlooking?

Comment: Have you tried to use VGrid.SetCellValue(VGrid.GetRowByName("rowcity"), e.RecordIndex, city);

Comment: Don't have that method available. Must be in a newer version than we have. Thanks, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `CustomUnboundData` event is how to accomplish this.

EDIT: In a rush, sorry...

The event fires as many times as there are unbound fields.

In the eventhandler, you examine the eventargs `fieldname` property (in  a switch statment) and set the value of the fieldname(s) you want to set.

Comment: Can you add more information? This answer seems more like a comment without a small example.